# Mongoose / JavaScript - Saving error - undefined object

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am trying to save a `match` between 2 `teams`, I am passing the 2 `teams` through a drop down list.

When I use `util.log` to output the `homeTeam` to the console when INSIDE the `Team.findByKey` method it works successfully and here is the output:

```
3 Mar 19:52:33 - { name: 'Liverpool',
  _id: 51312074bb176ba624000007,
  __v: 0,
  key: 1362174068837 }
```

But as soon as I try to do this outside of this method I get the following output which means that when I try to save this as a match, the hometeam appears as just `undefined` rather than the id of the `hometeam`:

```
3 Mar 19:54:09 - [object Object]
```

My problem is that I am eventually wanting to save both a home team and an away team to the same match in one save. The code for saving a match works when inside the `Team.findByKey` method which is as follows:

```
  app.get('/save/matchTest', function(req, res) {
    var key = 1362174006191; // Man Utd 51312036bb176ba624000001
    Team.findByKey(key, function(err, team) {
      util.log(team);
      if(err) {
        util.log("Error occured");
      }
      if(!team) { 
        util.log("The team does not exist");
      }
      var match = new Match({
        hometeam: team._id
      });
      match.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
          util.log('Error while saving Match: ' + util.inspect(err));
          res.send("An error occured whilst saving the match");
        } else {
          res.send("Saved the match");
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

But what I want to do is to be able to save a match with the following

```
var match = new Match({
    hometeam: homeTeam._id,
    awayteam: awayTeam._id
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the relevant code:

JavaScript

```
submitMatch = function(){
    var homeId = $("#homeTeamList").val();
    var awayId = $("#awayTeamList").val();

    //alert("home: " + homeId + " away: " + awayId);

    // Frontend sends the data
    var matchForm = {
        homeKey : $('#homeTeamList').val(),
        awayKey : $('#awayTeamList').val()
    };

    // Basic validation
    $.post('/save/match', {'matchForm' : matchForm}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

};
```

/save/match

```
  app.post('/save/match', function(req, res) {
    util.log('Serving request for url [GET] ' + req.route.path);
    // Output to console to test what is being passed to Save Match
    // Entire body passed to console
    //console.log('body: ', req.body);
    // Entire matchForm from body
    //console.log('matchForm: ', req.body.matchForm);
    // Home Key from matchForm
    //console.log('homeKey: ', req.body.matchForm.homeKey);
    // Away Key from matchForm
    //console.log('awayKey: ', req.body.matchForm.awayKey);

    // Get data from match Form
    var matchForm = req.body.matchForm;

    // Check if a match with 2 teams has been submitted
    if(matchForm.homeKey === '' || matchForm.homeKey === undefined ||
        matchForm.awayKey === '' || matchForm.awayKey === undefined){
      // Not a valid match
      util.log('Not valid match');
    } else {
      var homeId = matchForm.homeKey;
      var awayId = matchForm.awayKey;

      var homeTeam = Team.findByKey(homeId, function(err, homeTeam) {
        util.log(homeTeam);
        if(err) {
          util.log("Error occured");
        }
        if(!homeTeam) { 
          util.log("The home team does not exist");
        }
      });

      var match = new Match({
        hometeam: homeTeam._id
      });

      //util.log(match);

    }
  });
```

Comment: Was just looking at this, but it's a bit overwhelming.  Can you simplify your question?

Comment: A lot to read I know sorry, `findByKey` retrieves a `Team` based on the `key` passed to it. `matchForm` is passed to this function with the `key` for the `home` and `away` teams, I want to use these 2 keys in order to find the 2 teams and store them in a new `Match` as `hometeam` and `awayteam`. I have used a reference to a `Team` Schema here, when I do the `findByKey` method and output to console INSIDE this it outputs to the console that yes this is `Liverpool` for example and it has found the correct `Team`. But outside of this method, if I output the result I get `[object Object]`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Hope this helps, I also tried outputting the Match after attempting to save it and the `hometeam` is saved as `undefined` due to it not knowing what this `team` is. I'm stuck because I am wanting to find the `home` and `away` teams in order to save them to the same `match`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/save/match` you're using the value of `homeTeam` in the `Match` constructor before it's been set by the callback.  You need to create the `Match` inside both the home and away team `findByKey` callbacks like this:

```
Team.findByKey(homeId, function(err, homeTeam) {
  util.log(homeTeam);
  if(err) {
    return util.log("Error occured");
  }
  if(!homeTeam) { 
    return util.log("The home team does not exist");
  }

  Team.findByKey(awayId, function(err, awayTeam) {
    util.log(awayTeam);
    if(err) {
      return util.log("Error occured");
    }
    if(!awayTeam) { 
      return util.log("The away team does not exist");
    }

    var match = new Match({
      hometeam: homeTeam._id,
      awayteam: awayTeam._id
    });
  });
});
```

To look up the home and away teams in parallel while still keeping your code organized, you'll want to look at using a flow control library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: Is there another way to do something reasonably organized without using something like async? It looks very complex to me and looks like something I don't think I could do. The help is much appreciated.

Comment: @germainelol The 'simple' approach is to keep nesting callbacks, but learning to use a flow control library like async is a pretty vital skill for node.js and is very easy to use once you 'get' it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, are you able to provide an example using a nested callback approach as you mention? I will try to implement that for the time being, I will need to look for some sort of tutorials for using async for sure.